# "Missing required module" when pod library is installed in one Target only

Tags: swift, cocoa, firebase, cocoapods

I'm embedding **frwkproject.xcodeproj** product (**frwkproject.framework**) in the **mainproject.xcodeproj** project.

I am trying to use Firebase Library in the **frwkproject.framework** only. Using this cocoa pods:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'frwkproject.xcworkspace'

abstract_target 'Shows' do

    pod 'Toaster'

    target 'frwkproject' do
        project 'frwkproject/frwkproject.xcworkspace'
        pod 'Firebase/Core'
        pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    end

    target 'mainproject' do
        project 'mainproject/mainproject.xcodeproj'
    end 

end
```

In the **mainproject** project I have imported the framework with:

```
import frwkproject
```

And this error appears: **"Missing required module Firebase"**

Importing the cocoa pods library in both projects avoids this problem. Like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'frwkproject.xcworkspace'

abstract_target 'Shows' do

    pod 'Toaster'

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'

    target 'frwkproject' do
        project 'frwkproject/frwkproject.xcworkspace'
    end

    target 'mainproject' do
        project 'mainproject/mainproject.xcodeproj'
    end 

end
```

But **Firebase will crash when imported in both project**.

Is it possible to **implement Firebase in the framework project only**?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got exactly the same problem. Here is how I've resolved it:

1. added

   ```
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   ```

   in a child project pod target
2. added

   ```
   pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac'
   pod 'nanopb'
   ```

   in a main project pod target (these are dynamic pod dependencies of Firebase)
3. added recursive `$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Firebase` in main target Build Settings -> Header Search Paths (got that idea from [here](http://www.prettyitgirl.com/2017/07/how-to-fix-missing-required-module-in.html)).

Hope that helps!